# Spark SQL on Google Compute Engine issue

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-hadoop

We are using bdutil 1.1 to deploy a Spark (1.2.0) cluster. However, we are having an issue when we launch our spark script:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.registerTempTable.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:346)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anonfun$4.apply(HiveContext.scala:235)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anonfun$4.apply(HiveContext.scala:231)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.x$3$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:231)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.x$3(HiveContext.scala:229)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:229)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf(HiveContext.scala:229)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.<init>(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$1.<init>(HiveContext.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.catalog$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.catalog(HiveContext.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.catalog(HiveContext.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.registerRDDAsTable(SQLContext.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDDLike$class.registerTempTable(SchemaRDDLike.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSchemaRDD.registerTempTable(JavaSchemaRDD.scala:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1412)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
... 31 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Class org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory was not found.
```

The script works on my laptop. I have datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar in the /home/hadoop/spark-install/lib path.

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: It appears that `org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory` is not on the classpath.

Comment: I tried to add  "--jars /home/hadoop/spark-install/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar" at the end of my spark-submit command but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add :

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH=/home/hadoop/spark-install/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/home/hadoop/spark-install/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/home/hadoop/spark-install/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar
```

before my spark-submit command:

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH=/home/hadoop/spark-install/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/home/hadoop/spark-install/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/home/hadoop/spark-install/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar ../hadoop/spark-install/bin/spark-submit main.py --master spark://spark-m:7077
```